# SQL split based on delimeter, keep only second element

Tags: sql-server, string, split, delimiter

I have T-SQL code and am researching how to split

```
Aruba\abc
Spain\defg
New Zealand\qwerty
Antartica\sporty
```

Such that the column outputs

```
abc
defg
qwerty
sporty
```

So far, I found something like this,

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx

But it splits column based on delimiters into new columns.

I wish to keep the information AFTER the delimiter `\`

Please advise

Comment: Look into charindex and substring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(ColName , LEN(ColName) - CHARINDEX('\', ColName) )
FROM TABLEName
```

OR

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(ColName , '\' , '.'),1)
FROM TableName
```

Comment: @m-ali I like the `PARSENAME`

Comment: In PARSENAME(REPLACE(ColName , '\' , '.'),1) what exactly is the use of `'.'`  as the third parameter in Replace function?

Answer (score 1):

If you have it as a variable example:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50) = 'aruba\abc'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('\', @str)+1, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('\', @str) )
```

If you have it in a table example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column1,CHARINDEX('\', column1)+1, LEN(column1) - CHARINDEX('\', column1) )
FROM table1
```

Here's a sqlfiddle of it working : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85de5/1